# Jinja's tag 'raw' in Django throws an error - 'Did you forget to register or load this tag?'

Tags: python, django, escaping, mustache, ninja

**I'm using:**

- Django (w/ Jinja)
- Mustache (for parsing JS vars)

**The context:**

- I'm trying to use Jinja's {% raw %}{% endraw %} tags in order to escape the similar syntax of the Mustache's markers in the HTML code. Nevertheless, Django throws an error 'Did you forget to register or load this tag?'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using Jinja. That is an error from the Django template language. In that language the tag you need is called [`verbatim`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim).

Comment: Indeed. Thanks a lot!